# How implement AdMob in Cordova/Phonegap 1.9.0 for iOS

Tags: ios, cordova, admob

I use Cordova 1.9.0, try implement Admob ads for iOS and get an error at self.viewController...: property viewController not found.
I tried modalViewController, parentViewController,... but it doesn't work correctly.
How implement AdMob for iOS?
I need to enable/disable ads from javascript.
Link to  instruction: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/phonegap/_Lf4o6xiUK0
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

For integrating admob in ios phonegap follow this steps

1. Create your normal, everyday phonegap (1.0.0) project in xcode
2. Import the GoogleAdMobAdsSDK folder and the required AdMob frameworks (I believe the only one that wasn’t already in the phonegap project was MessageUI.framework)
3. In AppDelegate.h – implement  then #import “GADBannerView.h” & add  GADBannerView *bannerView_; to your @interface
4. In AppDelegate.m –  #define MY_BANNER_UNIT_ID @”Your AdMob Publisher ID# Here”
   Now the tricky part. This caused me to bang my head on the wall for
   some time

   5.) Change your method webViewDidFinishLoad to this . . .

   (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)theWebView
   {

   ```
   bannerView_ = [[GADBannerView alloc]init];
   [bannerView_ setDelegate:self];
   [bannerView_ setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 50)];

   // Specify the ad's "unit identifier." This is your AdMob Publisher ID.
   bannerView_.adUnitID = MY_BANNER_UNIT_ID;

   // Let the runtime know which UIViewController to restore after taking
   // the user wherever the ad goes and add it to the view hierarchy.
   bannerView_.rootViewController = self.viewController;
   [self.viewController.view addSubview:bannerView_];

   // Initiate a generic request to load it with an ad.
   [bannerView_ loadRequest:[GADRequest request]];

   // only valid if AdGap.plist specifies a protocol to handle
   if(self.invokeString)
   {
       // this is passed before the deviceready event is fired, so you can access it in js when you receive deviceready
       NSString* jsString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"var invokeString = \"%@\";", self.invokeString];
       [theWebView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:jsString];
   }
   return [ super webViewDidFinishLoad:theWebView ];
   ```

   }

and it's done

If you still find any query than have a look at this guide carefully
[APPLYING ADMOB TO PHONEGAP(IOS)](http://iphone.keyvisuals.com/iphonedev/implementing-admob-ads-in-a-phonegap-project-for-ios-no-plugins-required/)

Comment: No problem with phonegap 1.0.0 but i need Cordova 1.9.0.

Comment: This should still work with Cordova, the only thing you need to make sure you're doing is that you're changing the size of the webview to make room to display the GADBannerView (decrease its height by the height of the GADBannerView)

Answer (score 0):

Try using this plugin [Click to view](https://github.com/appfeel/admob-google-cordova)
Add the plugin

```
cordova plugin add cordova-admob
```

Then add the code below to your javascript file and change ca-app-pub-XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/BBBBBBBBBB to your id.

```
function onDeviceReady() {
  document.removeEventListener('deviceready', onDeviceReady, false);

  // Set AdMobAds options:
  admob.setOptions({
    publisherId:          "ca-app-pub-XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/BBBBBBBBBB",  // Required
    interstitialAdId:     "ca-app-pub-XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/IIIIIIIIII",  // Optional
  });

  // Start showing banners (automatic when autoShowBanner is set to true)
  admob.createBannerView();

  // Request interstitial (will present automatically when autoShowInterstitial is set to true)
  admob.requestInterstitialAd();
}

document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
```